# SQL incremential count for X with a Left Outer Join

Tags: sql-server, count, increment

I'm trying to get an incremental count for `StSe.ID` based incrementally on `StVS.ID`

e.g. desired outcome:

[image]

My SQL so far..

```
Select top (1000)

  StVS.ID AS 'SessionID',
  StSe.ID AS 'Search ID',

  --I need this to be an incremental count for search count based on Session ID
  count (StVS.ID) AS 'Search ID sequence' 

From Stats_VisitorSessions StVs
  Left join Stats_VisitorSearches StSe  WITH (NOLOCK) on StSe.SessionID=StVs.SessionID
  Left join Stats_Visitors StV WITH (NOLOCK) on StV.VisitorID=StVs.VisitorID
group by StVS.ID, StSe.ID
Order by StVs.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()` with Partition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

*Edit* - apologies, missed the point about `NULL`s from the LOJ:

```
Select top (1000)

  StVS.ID AS 'SessionID',
  StSe.ID AS 'Search ID',
  CASE WHEN StSe.ID IS NULL 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StVS.ID ORDER BY StSe.ID ASC) 
       END AS Sequence

From Stats_VisitorSessions StVs
  Left join Stats_VisitorSearches StSe on StSe.SessionID=StVs.SessionID
  Left join Stats_Visitors StV on StV.VisitorID=StVs.VisitorID
group by StVS.ID, StSe.ID
Order by StVs.ID;
```

I've ordered by `Searchid` (assuming its time incrementing) but if you have a better field like a timestamp, suggest order by that.